# Problema al crear este procedimiento (PROCEDURE) en MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

estoy intentado hacer este procedimiento, pero me dice que tento un **error de sintaxis**

```
   CREATE PROCEDURE insertar_usuario(
                            IN nombre VARCHAR(300), 
                            IN apellidos VARCHAR(300), 
                            IN email VARCHAR(300), 
                            IN password VARCHAR(300), 
                            IN fecha_nacimiento DATE, 
                            IN pais VARCHAR(300))
(
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO usuarios(nombre,apellidos,email,password,fecha_nacimiento,pais) 
    VALUES(nombre,apellidos,email,password,fecha_nacimiento,pais);

END;
);
```

**Error:**

> Error de SQL (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BEGIN    INSERT INTO usuarios(nombre,apellidos,email,password,fecha_nacimiento' at line 9

Comment: **IN nombre VARCHAR, nombre** puede que sea esa linea la que está reclamando y ya que haces la prueba podrías colocar **CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE**

Comment: No era eso, he actualizado la pregunta.Un saludo

Answer (score 2):

Tienes varios errores. La respuesta rápida es que pruebes lo siguiente (cambiando los largos máximos de los campos `VARCHAR`):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE insertar_usuario(IN nombre VARCHAR(15),
                                  IN apellidos VARCHAR(15), 
                                  IN email VARCHAR(15), 
                                  IN password VARCHAR(15), 
                                  IN fecha_nacimiento DATE, 
                                  IN pais VARCHAR(15))
    INSERT INTO usuarios(nombre,apellidos,email,password,fecha_nacimiento,pais) VALUES (nombre,apellidos,email,password,fecha_nacimiento,pais);
```

La respuesta larga sería la siguiente:

- Necesitas especificar el largo máximo a las cadenas de largo variable con `VARCHAR(<largo>)`.
- No necesitas el `BEGIN`, `END` ni los paréntesis para crear un procedmiento.
- Como te dijeron en la primera respuesta, en el primer parámetro repites `nombre` después de la coma.

Comment: He establecido los maximos,he quitado los BEGIN y END y el parametro repetido  ese ('nombre') y sigue sin ir

Comment: ¿Y cual es el mensaje de error?

Comment: He actualizado la pregunta, ahi esta todo. Un saludo

Comment: Quita el `BEGIN`, ponlo tal y como yo lo he puesto, no lo necesitas.

Comment: Por lo visto PL/SQL es solo de ORACLE y yo estaba usando MySQL... Confusion mia

Comment: Estimado, recomiendo que marques alguna respuesta como correcta para dar cierre correcto al flujo de preguntas.

Answer (score 0):

En el primer parámetro repites `nombre` después de la coma.

debería ser así:

```
...
IN nombre VARCHAR,
...
```

Comment: Lo he quitado y sigue sin ir, tengo mas fallos

Answer (score 0):

Solo debes quitar lo que dice @marc solo quita `nombre` que esta despues de la coma, quedaria algo asi:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE insertar_usuario @nombre VARCHAR(300), 
                         @apellidos VARCHAR(300), 
                         @email VARCHAR(300), 
                         @password VARCHAR(300), 
                         @fecha_nacimiento DATE, 
                         @pais VARCHAR(300)
as
     INSERT INTO usuarios(nombre,apellidos,email,password,fecha_nacimiento,pais) 
     VALUES(nombre,apellidos,email,password,fecha_nacimiento,pais);
END
GO
```

Saludos :D

Comment: He quitado ese parametro repetido erroneamente y sigue sin ir.

Comment: que error sale ?

Comment: Mira la corregí, intenta asi a ver

Answer (score 0):

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insertar_usuario(
                            IN nombre VARCHAR(300), 
                            IN apellidos VARCHAR(300), 
                            IN email VARCHAR(300), 
                            IN password VARCHAR(300), 
                            IN fecha_nacimiento DATE, 
                            IN pais VARCHAR(300))

BEGIN
    INSERT INTO usuarios(nombre,apellidos,email,password,fecha_nacimiento,pais) 
    VALUES(nombre,apellidos,email,password,fecha_nacimiento,pais);

END;
/
```

Creo que los paréntesis son el problema de sintaxis, prueba con este código.